# SoilGrids - predicted probability

Tags: soilgrids

The question is related to interpretation of grids representing soil types separately, like salty soils:

TAXNWRB_Gleyic.Solonetz

TAXNWRB_Calcic.Solonetz

TAXNWRB_Haplic.Solonetz

TAXNWRB_Mollic.Solonetz

TAXNWRB_Gypsic.Solonchaks

TAXNWRB_Haplic.Solonchaks..Sodic

TAXNWRB_Haplic.Solonchaks

It is written that the units are "Predicted probability in percent" but the pixel values are in range between 0-10 (in one case even 12?).

Are those values representing percentage divided by 10? Or it is something else behind them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the rasters with predictions for the World Reference Base (WRB) are encoded with 8-bit positive integers (`Byte` type for GDAL). The domain interval is [0; 100] and empty values are encoded with 255. This is all in the raster meta-data, that you may access with `gdalinfo`:

```
$ gdalinfo TAXNWRB_Gleyic.Solonetz_250m_ll.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
[...]
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  ATTRIBUTE_LABEL=TAXNWRB
  ATTRIBUTE_MEASUREMENT_RESOLUTION=1
  ATTRIBUTE_TITLE=Predicted probability in percent for: Gleyic Solonetz
  ATTRIBUTE_UNITS_OF_MEASURE=percent
  CITATION_ADDRESS=tom.hengl@isric.org
  CITATION_ORIGINATOR=ISRIC - World Soil Information
  CITATION_URL=http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0169748
  CONFIDENCE_INTERVAL=M
  DATA_FORMAT=Byte
  DEPTH=None
  DOWNLOAD_FTP_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/TAXNWRB_Gleyic.Solonetz_250m_ll.tif
  HORIZON_LOWER_DEPTH=2.00 m
  HORIZON_UPPER_DEPTH=0.00 m
  KEYWORD1=WRB
  KEYWORD2=Solonetz
  NO_DATA=255
  PROJECT_URL=http://soilgrids.org
  PUBLICATION_DATE=2017-03-10
  RANGE_DOMAIN_MAXIMUM=100
  RANGE_DOMAIN_MINIMUM=0
  SERIES_NAME=SoilGrids250m
  SLD_NAME=soilgrids250m:PROB
  SLD_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/legends/PROB.sld
  TECHNICAL_SPECIFICATIONS_URL=https://github.com/ISRICWorldSoil/SoilGrids250m
[...]
```

Comment: So to answer the question, the values 0-12 are actually percentages?

Comment: You can verify that the meta-data field `ATTRIBUTE_UNITS_OF_MEASURE` indicates percentage as unit.

Comment: To conclude: In the above mentioned example (where the salty soils were analyzed) it is a very low occurring probability of these soil types in the extent area. Right?

Comment: If the value for a cell in this raster is 10, it means there is a 10% probability of the soil in that cell being a Gleyic Solonetz.